# Problemas com o querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

O querySelectorAll funciona normalmente no Firefox, porém, no Chrome não. Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar em tal questão, segue o código.

```
<script>
        document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(link => {
            let conteudo = document.getElementById('conteudo')
            link.onclick = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                fetch(link.href)
                    .then(resp => resp.text())
                    .then(html => conteudo.innerHTML = html)
            }
        })
    </script>
```

No console aparece o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch at
>   HTMLAnchorElement.link.onclick

HTML

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="background-color: #000080; height: 40px; font: bold 15px Arial, sans-serif;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style = "font: italic 20px Verdana;">KAUYYZI</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <i class="fa fa-user-md"></i>
            <span class="icon icon-bar">A</span>
            <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="tabela.html">Contato</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="agendamentoPaciente.html">Agendamento</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<section id="conteudo"></section>
<footer class = "ftr">
    KAUYYZI 2018 &copy;
</footer>
```

Erro Network

> URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Comment: Gabriel, o que te dá `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('a').length`);`? Seria interessante juntares o HTML que te dá esse problema...

Comment: Seu código parece funcionar normalmente no Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/zwz9kmvn/

Comment: Qual é o endereço que você tenta acessar no fetch? Se for de outro domínio, o browser vai bloquear o acesso.

Comment: @bfavaretto como está em fase de construção o Web Site, está no WAMP.

Comment: @Gabriel mas qual a URL que esta no link que clicou que ocasionou a falha, pode ser problema de origem cruzada

Comment: @Gabriel posta os links usados no `<a href>` por favor. Assim conseguiremos ajudar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o problema que funciona no Firefox e no Chrome não...

Comment: Vai no console novamente, mas na aba network (se seu navegador estiver em portugues a aba se chama Rede), clica nela, então volta no teu site e clica em qualquer link, depois volte na janela do console aba rede, veja as requisições HTTP, a que vc clicou do link deve estar com algum erro. Nos informe o erro, isso deve ajudar a resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Sabia, era erro de CORS (origem cruzada). Então agora diga, qual link exatamente causou o erro `URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.` ?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu estou testando localmente, isso geraria o erro? algo do tipo isso aqui seria, file:///C:/XXX/XXX%20XXX/Desktop/ex/agendamentoPaciente.html.

Comment: Então é isso. Só vai funcionar no protocolo HTTP.

Comment: Gabriel, finalize a questão marcando ✓ em uma das repostas. Não deixe a pergunta em aberto porque não é interessante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O protocolo `FILE:///` não é permitido interagir com `fetch` e nem Ajax (`XmlHttpRequest`), coloque para rodar em um servidor HTTP local, como Apache, existem muitos programas, como:

- Wamp
- Xampp
- EasyPHP

Vai ter que mover a sua pasta `file:///C:/XXX/XXX%20XXX/Desktop/ex/` para dentro da pasta do Wamp (acho que é a pasta `www`)

E então acessar assim no navegador `http://localhost/ex/`

Answer (score 1):

O problema não é com o `querySelectorAll`, que funciona normalmente no seu código. O problema está no uso do `fetch` em arquivos locais usando o Chrome.

O Firefox (e o Edge) permite acessar arquivos locais via `fetch` (por isso não apresentou erro), desde que a página que esteja usando a API também seja local. E desde também que o protocolo `file:///` não seja explícito (exceto no Edge, que aceita explícito ou não):

```
<a href="pagina.html">link</a> OK!
<a href="file:///pagina.html">link</a> BLOQUEIA!
```

Já o Chrome, por questões de segurança e política do navegador, bloqueia tal acesso, permitindo apenas via protocolo HTTP (ou HTTPS).

Você pode usar o Firefox para testar a API localmente, e quando subir os arquivos para um servidor HTTP, irá funcionar normalmente no Chrome e demais navegadores compatíveis com a API.

Comment: Comentando, e de certa forma contra-argumentando, a questão do suporte à API `fetch`, atualmente apenas o IE 11 não suporta, tal como descrito no [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch), o que faz dela bastante segura para se usar em produção.

Comment: Concordo em parte. Eu não gosto da ideia de usar algo que não haja suporte ao IE 11 ou qualquer outro navegador moderno.

Comment: Resolvi remover a informação da resposta pq acho até que essa informação na documentação está defasada :D

Comment: Sim, a *polyfill* ainda é necessária, mas já pode usar sem medo :D